# Confused with job application status

Tags: job-offer, internship, follow-up

I did a phone interview for Internship in a very reputed company for Network Engineering role, the interview went really well and at the end, the interviewer said:

> I'm forwarding this conversation to the recruiting manager, she will
>   compare it with other applicants and will decide if we'll take further action.
>   It's an impressive resume and has been a great interview. It was really nice talking to you

It's been 2 weeks and no email from the company, I even sent an email enquiring about the application status but no reply. Did I lose the opportunity?

Comment: Why are you asking on here?  It's been two weeks, call them up and ask them, they are the only ones that can answer that question.

Comment: I'm asking here to understand what the recruiter perspective and what exactly happens in such scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Odds are that they have decided not to hire you. Sometimes when a company decides they don't want you they'll send you an email or a letter saying they hired someone else, but most of the time they don't, they just don't call you back.

It's also possible that they're still interviewing other candidates, thinking about it, whatever.

Regardless of what they're doing, DON'T sit by your phone waiting for them to call. Apply for other jobs. Get your resume out there.